# How do I use the "bpy.ops.wm.link" operator to link multiple files while still keeping parenting/hierarchy order?

Tags: python, linked-data

I'm writing a script that links certain objects from a .blend file.

When I do this manually I select the objects I want to link by shift-clicking on them in the browser window. They get linked to the blender scene and keep their parenting order from the original file.

However when I do that via script that loops over a list of all the objects I want to link, they get linked without parenting being kept.
I cannot parent the linked objects in the scene without turning them into proxys, which change their name. I don't want to make them into proxies.

Here's the operator that links the objects from a list (tuple list):

```
class GetChar(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "link.char"
    bl_label = "Links the objects of a character to the scene"

    def execute(self, context):


    #   Run function that makes the list of objects to link:
        item_cb(self, context)

    #   Looping over the objects:
        if bpy.ops.wm.link.poll():
            for obj in SCENE_PT_object_lib.obs:
                name = str(obj[0])
                # Filter objects in list
                if not name.startswith("WGT"):      
                    bpy.ops.wm.link(filepath=filename, directory=directory, filename=name, link=True)


        return {'FINISHED'}
```

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated :)

Thank you!

Comment: are you using [this script](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?319691-Append-objects-from-blend-%28yes-i-know-i-know-%29), there is couple of things to change in it

Comment: Parts of it, yes

Comment: see if [this](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/35220) helps ?